# How can I link to an App Store Item from TVML?

Tags: javascript, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I am trying to link to an item on the App Store from my TVML based app.
Is this possible and if yes how would I handle external links in the presenter.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found a solution:**
Register a Swift-Function which TVJS can talk to.

```
//Javascript code from presenter.js
goToApp('<customUrlOfApp>://');
```

and

```
/* AppDelegate.swift jsContext Function */
func appController(appController: TVApplicationController, evaluateAppJavaScriptInContext jsContext: JSContext){
    let goToApp : @convention(block) (NSString!) -> Void = {
        (url : NSString!) -> Void in
        if let appURL = NSURL(string: url as String) {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appURL)
            print("[GoToUrl]: \(url)\n")
        }
    }
    jsContext.setObject(unsafeBitCast(goToApp, AnyObject.self), forKeyedSubscript: "goToApp")
}
```

Comment: does openUrl work in tvOS?   I've tried it with YouTube and it doesn't work